# msbuild fails in Teamcity

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, teamcity

I might be missing something really simple here. I'm trying to build a solution in Teamcity using msbuild but it always keeps failing with the below error.

```
'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have VS2017 installed and when I run the solution locally through command line on the same Teamcity agent, it works perfectly with the following comments.

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.4.8.50001 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

But for some reason it always fails on teamcity. I'm at a loss as to what am I missing here. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Following is the command that I'm using to compile the solution

```
msbuild hello.sln /t:Rebuild
```

Comment: MSBuild isn't in the PATH by default, with reason, so that could be why teamcity doesn't find the command (though I'm not sure how it can be that your command line know it, unless you actually started a Developer Command prompt or so). Do the right thing and use TeamCity's MSBuild runner? https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/MSBuild

Comment: Also make sure your TC is relatively up to date.  IIRC, VS2017's new installation strategy wasn't supported until TC 10.0.4 or so.

Answer (score 3):

> msbuild fails in Teamcity

Agree with stijn. According to the error log, it seems MSBuild not in the default path, so it could not be found.

To resolve this issue, you should make sure you have installed the Visual Studio 2017 or Microsoft Build Tools on the teamcity agent and need to properly configure your build runner, especially MSBuild version.

Besides, you can also try to create environment variable "MSBuild"  and set it to the path of MSBuild.exe in your teamcity agent.

The default path of MSBuild for Visual Studio 2017 is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
```

If above not help you, please share us your configuration about Build Runner.

Comment: When setting the Path variable make sure you set the one from System vars not User vars. Reseting the server will ensure that Teamcity has access to the new vars. If you set for User vars, your local cmd will work, but teamcity will still have trouble. This fixed it for me.